# angular how to make data if name is duplicate don't show

Tags: javascript, angular

how to make if data name is duplicate more than 20, it shouldn't display. it should display only one data when the name is already displayed
 `list.component.ts`

```
gaugeChart() {

        this.gaugeOption = [];

        this.global.getData(`/services/getData.php`)
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.rowData = res;
            this.rowData.forEach((room) => {
              this.gaugeOption.push({
                title: {
                  text: room.sensor,
                  left: '5%',
                  top: '5%',
                  textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {
                  formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c}°"
                },
                toolbox: {
                  show: true,
                  feature: {
                    mark: { show: false },
                    restore: { show: false },
                    saveAsImage: { show: false }
                  }
                },
                series: [
                  {
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    type: 'gauge',
                    center: ['40%', '70%'],
                    splitNumber: 10,
                    radius: '70%',
                    axisLine: {
                      lineStyle: {
                        color: [[0.2, '#48b'], [0.8, '#228b22'], [1, '#ff0000']],
                        width: 8
                      }
                    },
                    axisTick: {
                      splitNumber: 10,
                      length: 12,
                      lineStyle: {
                        color: 'auto'
                      }
                    },
                    axisLabel: {
                      textStyle: {
                        color: 'auto'
                      }
                    },
                    splitLine: {
                      show: true,
                      length: 30,
                      lineStyle: {
                        color: 'auto'
                      }
                    },
                    pointer: {
                      width: 5
                    },
                    title: {
                      show: true,
                      offsetCenter: [0, '65%'],
                      textStyle: {
                        fontWeight: 'bolder'
                      }
                    },
                    detail: {
                      formatter: '{value}°',
                      textStyle: {
                        color: 'auto',
                        fontWeight: 'bolder'
                      }
                    },
                    data: [{ value: room.temperature, name: "Temperature" }]
                  }
                ]
              });
            });
```

`list.component.html`

```
<ul class="cards">
        <li class="cards__item" *ngFor="let data of gaugeOption; let i = index">
          <div class="card">
            <div echarts [options]="data" id="{{'chart-' + i}}" [autoResize]="true"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
      </ul>
```

The output will display all 20 duplicated names which are `Room 1`.
It should display only one name if there are more of 20 duplicate records.

Comment: where is the room.name?

Comment: can you add more code ? specially your html

Comment: can you provide a response?

Comment: @bubbles already update my code

Comment: I still not figure out where the problem is, i do not find which name is duplicated ! a minimal reproducible example is needed to help you